# How to add this GraphQL data to my pie chart in highcharts?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, graphql, react-highcharts

I would appreciate any help that I can get with this

I need to plot a pie chart with 4 standard pies: ABC, BCD, CDE and DEF
Each Pie has a data point coming in from my GraphiQL resolver which looks like this:

```html
{
  "data": {
    "metrics": {
      "A": 56147.85,
      "B": 116480.51,
      "C": 56147.85,
      "D": 120329.45000000001,
    }
  }
}
```

**This is my highchart code for piechart**

```html
function PieChart() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(CONC, {
    variables: {
      Currency: 'USD',
      Date: {
        date: '2019-05-01',
        date_range: ['2019-05-01', '2019-06-10'],
      },
      Options: {
        a: {
          prop: '44',
          csprop: ['14', '14', '40', '60'],
        },
        d: {
          prop: '104',
          csprop: ['511', '289', '519', '62'],
        },
      },
      C: 'G',
      Incl: false,
      DFilters: [
        {
          by: 'P',
          values: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  });

  const Top = [];
  const First = [];
  const Second = [];
  const Rest = [];

  data &&
    data.metrics.forEach((e) => {
      Top.push(e['A']);
      First.push(e['B']);
      Second.push(e['C']);
      Rest.push(e['D']);
    });

  return (
    <HighchartWrapper
      chartOptions={{
        chart: {
          type: 'pie',
          height: 230,
          // width: 565,         
        },
        title: {
          text: '',
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
        },
        accessibility: {
          point: {
            valueSuffix: '%',
          },
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            },
          },
        },

        series: [
          {
            name: 'R',
            data: [
              { name: 'ABC', y: Top},            
              { name: 'BCD', y: First},
              { name: 'CDE', y: Second},
                { name: 'DEF', y: Rest},
            ],
          },
        ],
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default memo(PieChart);
```

**PROBLEM:**

The GraphiQL query is generating results.

But I believe it's the way I am trying to push data that's giving me an empty pie chart

Thank you all in advance

Comment: You're not using your `data` in `series`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get that. I am pushing the data like this already and using the same in the series:                                                                   
data.metrics.forEach((e) => {
      Top.push(e['A']);
      First.push(e['B']);
      Second.push(e['C']);
      Rest.push(e['D']);
    });

Comment: have you inspected that the data your component receives?

Comment: remove `memo` (doesn't make sense for component reading data inside) ... render some loading (read docs) and chart after data load/if data exists

Comment: Hi @SreeHarsha Gumma Shivaprakash, `y` values in data array should be numbers not arrays. Additionally, you probably unnecessarily using loop for: `data.metrics.forEach`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rnt8wv0a/

Comment: Thank you so much @ppotaczek .. this answer should help me .. will try it out and let you know .. appreciate that

Comment: Thank you so much @ppotaczek, the solution worked. Much appreciated. Goodnight